Go convert C function pointer to Go interface and call using reflect.Value.Call()
I'm making a dynamic library in go. I have a function that stores function pointers and names in map[string]interface{} and a function to dynamically call any function using reflect.
Here is my go code in file lib.go
package main

import (
    "C"
    "errors"
    "log"
    "reflect"
)

var Functions map[string]interface{}

//export RegisterFunc
func RegisterFunc(name string, function interface{}) error {
    if _, ok := Functions[name]; ok {
        log.Println("Function " + name + " is already defined")
        return errors.New("function " + name + " is already defined")
    }
    Functions[name] = function
    return nil
}

//export CallFunc
func CallFunc(name string, args []interface{}) ([]interface{}, error) {
    newArgs := []reflect.Value{}
    for _, arg := range args {
        newArgs = append(newArgs, reflect.ValueOf(arg))
    }
    function, ok := Functions[name]
    if !ok {
        log.Println("Function " + name + " is not defined")
        return nil, errors.New("function " + name + " is not defined")
    }
    result := reflect.ValueOf(function).Call(newArgs)
    newRes := []interface{}{}
    for _, res := range result {
        newRes = append(newRes, res.Interface())
    }
    return newRes, nil
}

func main() {}

And to compile to a dynamic library I use:
go build -o lib.so -buildmode=c-shared .\lib.go
I then want to use this functioning go library in C. But I don't know how to convert a C function pointer to a Go function pointer and then into an interface. I think I understand the difference between a C and a Go string and also the difference in other types but I don't know I could do this.
Here is my C code in main.c
The file lib.h is generated when lib.go is compiled by golang to a dll.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "lib.h"

void FunctionOne(GoInt x) {
    printf("FunctionOne(%d)", x);
    return x+2;
}

void FunctionTwo(GoInt x, bool y, GoString z) {
    printf("FunctionOne(%d, %d, %s)", x, y, z.p);
    return x*((int)y+1);
}

int main() {
    // What I want to do:

    // RegisterFunc("funcOne", &FunctionOne);
    // RegisterFunc("funcTwo", &FunctionTwo);

    // CallFunc_return retValue1 = CallFunc("funcOne", [5]);
    // if (retValue1.r1 != NULL) {
    //     printf("Error!");
    //     return 1;
    // }
    // for (size_t i = 0; i < retValue1.r0.len; i++)
    // {
    //     printf(retValue1.r0.data[i]);
    // }

    // CallFunc_return retValue2 = CallFunc("funcTwo", [4, true, "Hello"]);
    // if (retValue2.r1 != NULL) {
    //     printf("Error!");
    //     return 1;
    // }
    // for (size_t i = 0; i < retValue2.r0.len; i++)
    // {
    //     printf(retValue2.r0.data[i]);
    // }
    
    return 0;
}

Can I even do this and if I can how?
